# Creating multiple sections of a sphere to save as individual files

Tags: 3d-printing

I need to take a sphere and cut it into 6 segments of alternating colours (blue and yellow). I then need to save all the blue segments as one file and and all yellow segments as another file. This will give me two files I can then print with dual extrusion to create one ball of two different colours.

Can someone tell me how I can create a sphere, split it into 6 or 8 segments and then save two files (one with segments 1, 3, 5 & 7 and the second file with segments 2, 4, 6, & 8).

The final outcome will be for me to create something looking like this assuming i can apply the same principle to a cylinder and sphere.

NB: I caused confusion in a previous question so this is asking how i can create a file rather than the actual printing of it.

[image]

[image]